# MD-Sidenav - How to change the color of the backdrop?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I'm attempting to change the color of the backdrop that is drawn when you open a sidenav set to Over mode. I can't quite seem to find where to change the color and don't want the very harsh dark color it is currently set to.

### Relevant HTML

app.component.html

```
<md-sidenav-container class="sidenavContainer">
    <md-sidenav id="leftNav" color="primary" #sidenav mode="over" class="left-nav">
        <nav-menu (onSelected)="setTheme($event)"></nav-menu>
    </md-sidenav>

    <div class="main" [class.app-dark-theme]="isDarkTheme" [class.app-candy-theme]="isCandyTheme" [class.app-custom-theme]="isCustomTheme">
        <md-toolbar class="top-nav" color="primary">
            <button md-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
                <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
            </button>

            <div id="navBarTitle">Dashboard</div>
            <span class="nav-spacer"></span>
            <div>Signed in as: AdminUser</div>
            <md-icon class="nav-icon">
                <div routerLink="/settings" mdTooltip="Settings">settings</div>
            </md-icon>
            <md-icon class="nav-icon" mdTooltip="Help">help</md-icon>
        </md-toolbar>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

app.component.css

```
.main {
    position: fixed;
    top: 64px;
    width: 100%;
}

.sidenavContainer {
    height: 100%;
}

.nav-icon {
    padding: 0 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.top-nav {
    height: 64px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}

.left-nav {
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 2px #c0c0c0;
}
```

navmenu.component.html

```
<md-toolbar layout="row" color="primary">
    <h2> 
        <span>Side Panel</span> 
    </h2>
    <span class="nav-spacer"></span>

    <md-button class="close-icon" ng-click=close()>
        <md-icon>close</md-icon>
    </md-button>
</md-toolbar> 

<md-button-toggle-group class="toggle-box" [vertical]="true">
    <md-button-toggle>
        <dash-theme (onSelected)="getTheme($event)"></dash-theme>
    </md-button-toggle>
    <md-button-toggle routerLink="/admin/dashboard">
        Admin Dashboard
    </md-button-toggle>
    <md-button-toggle>
        User Dashboard
    </md-button-toggle>
</md-button-toggle-group>
```

navmenu.component.css

```
md-button-toggle-group, md-button-toggle {
    padding: 0px;
    width: 225px; 
}

.sidenav ul a {
    width: 100%;
}

button {
    width: 100%;
}

.close-icon {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 9px;
}

.nav-spacer {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Any way in which i can change the color would be helpful, I assume i'm just not seeing something seeing as this should most likely be a very standard feature for this component. Thank you for reading

Comment: Have you tried using `/deep/` selector?

Comment: I have not, how would that be used in this context? I truly am lost.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting this in you css file:

```
/deep/ .mat-sidenav-transition .mat-sidenav-backdrop.mat-sidenav-shown {
    background: skyblue;  /* replace skyblue with any color */ 
}
```

[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/sCSNQj?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

This work for me in Angular 11, if someone has the same problem than me, try putting this in your css file:

```
::ng-deep .mat-drawer-backdrop.mat-drawer-shown {
    background-color: rgba(53, 53, 53, 0.44);
}
```